# Qemu arm with versatilepb 3.board support hda image with kernel 3.17.6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, qemu

I am trying to build & run linux kernel 3.17.6 version for Qemu versatile board target.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel zImage-versatile -hdc rootfs.img
```

While running qemu with hda image, it reports

`Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
1f00           65536 mtdblock0  (driver?)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

Can anyone tell, what i am missing?
why does hda, other scsi drives are not recongnised.

I am trying for follow step from below link
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/HowToQemu#Build_Kernel_Image_From_Source

Comment: If i am using the prebuilt images  zImage-versatile-2.6.22. It seems to be mounting.  why later kernel is missing some thing.

Comment: Finally found issue, missing configuration. Enable SCSI Device Support.  It is under Device Drivers -> SCSI Device Support.

Enable SCSI Disk Support.  It is under Device Drivers -> SCSI Device Support.  I had enabled same scsi device support not figuring out it is scsi disk support. My eyes...